# Android - Drawing an image from assets, something weird is happening

Tags: java, android, image, null, drawing

I am loading an image from the assets folder to draw on a google map view as an overlay. In my try-catch statement, I attempt to load the image, otherwise return null.

What i don't understand is, upon stepping through the code time and time again, it gets to the load line and fails, thus returning null, but for some reason, despite returning a null image, the image is actually correctly loaded and drawing...??

If i run the program normally, it loads the image and displays it correctly as it should but the function is still returning a null bitmap everytime. Have i missed something here?

Here is the code I am using to load the image:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myActivity.getAssets().open("squirrel.jpg"));
```

Edit: 
I tried another random image, this time a .png and it is still doing the same thing but still loaded and drawing correctly.

Comment: Did you check if your are hitting this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066 ?

Comment: I guess that could be whats wrong, is it only with jpegs when this happens ?

Comment: @Jamie: could you please show the code of the try/catch block and how it's drawn?

Comment: tried your code works fine for me. make sure you have the jpg in assets folder. is your logcat saying about any exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger might be skipping to the return null line in the catch statement, because the debugger likes to make you think it's returning on a line that it actually isn't.